# Is it legal for my employer to ask me to work without contract?

Tags: termination, contract-extension

My full-time contract has expired 2 months ago. My employer told me that I have to convert my contract to a permanent role as I have completed more than 2 years with the company.

So I continued working without paper work (though the salary is paid) and waiting 2 months patiently for my employer to process the permanent role. Now things have changed as the head of the department resigned and we are going through reorganization.

Now my manager says that my permanent role depends on new head's vision. In the worst case I would be given a short contract extension.

Is it fair for the employer to keep me waiting in such uncertain situation? I am really stressed in this uncertain situation.

Comment: Where are you from?

Comment: You are talking in riddles. FTC? "perm"? Please keep in mind that this is not the LocalNet for your country. This is the "world wide" web. Please explain abbreviations and colloquialisms so everybody can understand them. I wasn't even able to google those terms, assuming you don't mean the federal trade commission or a hairstyle or a city in Russia.

Comment: FTC means 'fixed term contract' they're given as a form of extended probation or to provide cover for long term absence, such as maternity leave in Europe. Perm means permanent.

Comment: Being uncertain of your role is very stressful. You should find solace in knowing they want to keep you around. During a reorganization there are likely other employees that stress their position will become redundant.

Answer (score 2):

On one hand, it is not fair that you do not have the proper paperwork. It may even be illegal.

On the other hand, the entire company / department is under reorganization. While still important, your situation is a small part of the bigger problem for the company.

What you can do: wait a little longer, see what is going on. If your boss is normally a reasonable guy, keep in contact with him. Ask some question occasionally.

If you are really afraid of unpleasant consequences, you can start looking for a new job - as a last resort.

Of course, all the situation depends on the quality of the job - if you like it, enjoy it, if it has a good pay...